# I am looking for a book about an astronaut traveling to a moon and solving a murder mystery

Tags: story-identification, novel

The guy is sent in a weird sort of cryosleep state to some moon, I think a Galiliean moon or Titan, as a replacement to a dead base resident. At the end, they discover the dead person's body and then they're under attack at base by dog-like aliens (I specifically remember dog-like intelligence.) I also remember these sort of driveable rovers that they use. I think the cover is black with a silhouette of light around the moon because of the rising sun, and then the black moon. I read it around 2016, but might been later till 2018 so it released before then. I don't know if this helps, but I read it at a public library in Huddersfield, UK.

Comment: If you got it from a library, can you contact them and ask for your rental history?

Comment: @Valorum Oh! I should check. The library is closed rn, I will check on Tuesday when they are open.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [An Oath of Dogs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32830440-an-oath-of-dogs) by Wendy N. Wagner, although the cover doesn't match your description.

[image]

> The guy is sent in a weird sort of cryosleep state to some moon, I think a Galiliean moon or Titan, as a replacement to a dead base resident.

Quoting from a Goodreads review:

> *Standish and Hattie (her service dog) have come to the moon colony of Huginn in the Yggdrasil system to work in an outlying forestry community only to find that the man she has come to work for is dead and she has his job.*

Another item from your question:

> At the end, they discover the dead person's body and then they're under attack at base by dog-like aliens

From the review again:

> *The death of Duncan Chambers (Standish's predecessor) is the focus of a cover-up, there's a pack of wild dogs that's terrorizing the community*

And as for not finding his body until the end... another review makes it clear they haven't found the body at the start of the story:

> *Standish lands to find out her now former boss, Duncan, was reported ‘lost’ and believed to be dead and now she has his job*

Another reviewer mentions the dogs being telepathic, which may be relevant to the point you made about their intelligence.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late reply, but it doesn't look like that is the right book. Ty for the try tho!